# Как активировать плагин для подгруженного текстового поля ?

Tags: javascript

Текстовое поле возвращается сервером посредством ajax, к которому нужно применить визуальный редактор:
http://jqueryte.com/documentation

Comment: Есть вариант в success ajax вызвать метод:

$(".editor").jqte();

Comment: http://jqueryte.com/documentation#method-jqteVal